# Gson not converting JSONarray element to class object

Tags: java, json, class, object, gson

I have a JSONArray, I am trying to convert each element of the array as a class instance using gson.fromJson. My class is entirely made of string members. When the JSONarray element has all values and none are null, then it gets converted fine, however, when one of the elements is null, that member's value is not getting updated.

Example

```
    class A {
         string firstname;
         string lastname;
         string balance;

         //getters and setters
    }
```

An example of an element in the JSONarray is

```
    {"firstname":"John","secondname":"Brown","balance":null}
```

when I log this using

```
    logger.info("json - " + array.get(i).toString());
```

it logs fine.

However after doing this

```
    A obj = gson.fromJson(array.get(i).toString(), A.toClass);
    logger.info("Class instance - " + gson.toJson(obj);
```

I get this

```
    {"firstname":"John","secondname":"Brown"}
```

However, if balance has some value other than null, it works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try this.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
```

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Null-Object-Support